# Store downloaded gzip for future use by React JS

Tags: reactjs, file, middleware, epic

I was trying to write a React JS code that would download gzip - file from server once per day, and if the file was already downloaded today - use the downloaded one.

The code for downloading files was pretty easy and it works.

```
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'

const today = () => (new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10))

const schedules = () => concat(
    ...config.epgUrls.map(
        (url) =>
            ajax({
                url,
                method: 'GET',
                responseType: 'blob'
            })
    )
)

export const saveChannelsEpic =
    (action$) =>
        action$.pipe(
            ofType(SAVE_CHANNELS),
            mergeMap(
                () =>
                    schedules()
                        .pipe(
                            pluck('response'),
                            map((gzipped) => FileSaver.saveAs(gzipped, `${today()}.gz`)),
                            map(() => saveChannelsFulfilled()),
                            catchError((err) => {
                                console.table(err.message)
                                saveChannelsFailed(err.message)
                                return EMPTY
                            })
                        )
            )
        )
```

The problem begins when I want to read it from filesystem (actually from browser's Downloads folder).
Could anyone please advise?
I know that browsers are restricted to access filesystem, but is there any workaround? I mean accessing 'file://C:/Users/MyUser/Downloads/*.gz' or something like this.

p.s. I would gladly store the file in localStorage, but there appears to be a limit ~ 8 MB. My files are ~100MB unzipped and ~20MB gzipped.